# Are there any other RWBY characters that were based on other stories?

Tags: rwby

A lot of the RWBY characters are based on or made similar to popular storybook characters. eg:

- Ruby Rose - Red Riding Hood
- Weiss Schnee - Snow White
- Cinder Fall & Salem - Cinderella & her Fairy God Mother
- Sun - from Journey to the West.

Are there any other characters that were based on other stories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This isn't a perfect answer](http://rozalynpaige.tumblr.com/post/96151576797/who-rwby-characters-allude-toare-based-on) but most of these seem fairly accurate.

> Basically, for some reason, I thought it’d be fun to list the current
>   known characters/stories that characters are based on thus far. So,
>   yay?
>
> First of all, before the break, just gonna point out…
>
> Neo: Not the Cheshire Cat. That’s all I know. Not the Cheshire Cat,
>   but apparently someone else might be Cheshire.
>
> Team RWBY’s theme is fairy tales.
>
> Ruby Rose: Little Red Riding Hood
>
> Weiss Schnee: Snow White
>
> Blake Belladonna: Belle/beauty, of Beauty and the Beast
>
> Yang Xiao Long: Goldilocks
>
> Team JNPR’s theme is people who dressed as the opposite sex.
>
> Jaune Arc: Joan of Arc
>
> Nora Valkyrie: Thor (Apparently once crossdressed to get Mjolnir
>   back.)
>
> Pyrrha Nikos: Achilles (Apparently once crossdressed as a red-haired
>   woman named Pyrrha. Pyrrha Nikos has been noted in volume 2 to be
>   nicknamed The Invincible Girl.)
>
> Lie Ren: Mulan
>
> Onto other peeps.
>
> Cardin Winchester: Henry Beaufort, the Cardinal of Winchester, who was
>   responsible for Joan of Arc being burned at the stake.
>
> Velvet Scarlatina: The Velveteen Rabbit
>
> Ozpin: Oz, from the Wizard of Oz (duh?)
>
> Glynda Goodwitch: Glenda the Good Witch, from Wizard of Oz (duh??)
>
> Ironwood: Tin Man, from Wizard of Oz (Apparently?!)
>
> Penny: Pinocchio
>
> Peter Port: Peter, from Peter and the Wolf
>
> Bartholomew Oobleck: Bartholomew, from Bartholomew and the Oobleck
>
> Adam Taurus: Probably Beast, from Beauty and the Beast
>
> The White Fang: White Fang, from… White Fang, by Jack London
>
> Cinder Fall: Cinderella (Confirmed by Miles and Kerry)
>
> Roman Torchwick: Lampwick/Candlewick, from Pinocchio
>
> Mercury Black: Mercury/Hermes (note his symbol is a shoe with a wing
>   on it)
>
> Sun Wukong: Sun Wukong, from Journey to the West
>
> Neptune: Neptune/Poseidon
>
> Junior (Hei Xiong): Baby bear, from the tale of Goldilocks (His name
>   literally means Black Bear)
>
> (Bonus: Characters who we don’t know the basis of but have some ideas)
>
> Emerald Sustrai: Maybe Aladdin or Cleopatra
>
> Summer Rose: The poem The Last Rose of Summer
>
> Winter Schnee: Perhaps the Snow Queen (on which Frozen is based)
>
> Fox: Tod the fox from The Fox and the Hound, or Inari the fox god
>
> Qrow: Scarecrow, from The Wizard of Oz

Comment: Please quote the relevant sections of the link you have provided otherwise should that site goes down your answer will be invalidated

Comment: Done and done. It's pretty much the entire link xD

Answer (score 0):

In reply to Chrono D:

Actually, Qrow and Raven Branwen are based off of Odin's twin Ravens, Hugin and Munin. Scarecrow will most likely be the Vacuo headmaster, as Lionheart, the Minstral headmaster, was based off the Cowardly Lion.

There's also a theory that team RWBY double as versions of Dorothy and her companions as well (weiss as the tin man, blake as the cowardly lion, and yang as the scarecrow). The difference is the headmaster's weve seen so far were them without what they searched for, while weiss blake and yang have found their heart, courage, and brains by journeying with Ruby. The headmasters likely had no "Dorothy" to help them.

Comment: Just realized your post is 3 years old, and so was made well prior to seeing Lionheart in the series